# Why is the Windows Explorer not able to find a UUID string in a list of text files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, grep

I have a directory with all my PUtty log files. Now I would like to find the files containing a UUID. I know that the UUID is in one or more files. I tried it with Windows Explorer.

1. I searched with the search input field and got no results.
2. I particularly told the Windows Explorer to search through the file contents and got no result.

Because I knew that the UUID must be there I tried `grep` and got them at once:

```
XXX@XXX /d/User/XXX/PuTTY.log
$ grep -l 416eaefb-81ca-e9bc-a755-8ea8fd8f1b53 *
2015-03-17_092835_.log
2015-03-23_131134_.log
2015-03-23_153320_.log
```

What is wrong with my Windows Explorer? What do I need to do to get in the year 2015 in Windows the functionality of a damn old grep from 1973?

Answer (score 0):

The search functionality built into Windows has been broken since Vista. As with many other Windows features, Microsoft chose to dumb it down to make it more useful to the least skilled user, thereby making it borderline useless for developers, power users, and so on. I personally use [FileSeek](http://www.fileseek.ca/) and [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/), and highly recommend both.

Comment: "FileSeek" looks fine but "Everything" seems to need indexing. But my original question was how to tell Windows to do what `grep` does.

Comment: Aside from being able to actually find arbitrary text within files, what is it about grep that you want the Windows search to do? The two tools are quite different, after all: grep is a command line tool, whereas the search built into Windows only works in the GUI context of Explorer. Windows still has the FIND command-line tool, and it seems able to find arbitrary text within files reasonably well, but the Explorer-based search has some serious limitations. Also, note that you can install the excellent [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to get grep in Windows.